# Polish Matura Mistake in answers?

Tags: java, algorithm

in Polish matura from IT in task 5.1 we have to count of increasing subsequence largest than 3 in file which 310 lines with int values, series is when all piervous values in smaller than next.

In Answers we have the count of increasing subsequence largest than 3 is 14, but i always gets 11, and i dont have idea why.

Some one can tell me what's wrong?

My code:

```
static int Series = 0;
static int Big = 0;
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner In = new Scanner(System.in);
    String Line = "Seria 1: ";
    int Last = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(In.hasNext()){
        int Current = In.nextInt();
        if(Last<Current){
            Series++;
            Line +=Current+" ";
        }
        else{
            if(Series>=3){
                Big++;
                System.out.println(Line+"#");
                Line="Seria "+(Big+1)+": ";
            }
            Series = 0;
        }
        Last = Current;
    }
    System.out.println(Big);
    In.close();
}
```

There is a file with records: http://wklej.to/phpgW

Comment: it is not clear what "bigger series" is. Are you looking for largest increasing subsequence?

Comment: Not sure why [tag:c] is in the tags.

Comment: Also, please follow java's coding convention if you code injava. variable names and methods start with lower case letters (Last, Current, Big, Series, ....)

Comment: May a _series_ start with a value smaller than the value the previous _series_ terminated with?

Comment: Hmm you never reassign the variable `Last`, you never reset `Series` to zero. I don't think `Last` will ever not be smaller than `Current`, which also means that you will never reassign `Big` either.

Comment: Erwin Bolwidt yea, it's my mistake but it's not causes wrong answer, i take this mistake now, but i try do this task already a few weeks.

Comment: Could you paste a link to the original question text? Your program gives a sensible answer, but whether it gives the correct answer depends on the way the question was formulated.

Comment: First of all camelCase, secondly use `BufferedReader` for better efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as far as I know your program works correctly and returns what you expect. The problem might be the wording. "Amount of increasing subsequences >= 3" can actually refer to two distinct ways of approaching it:

- First one is your way, the end of the sequence is just before the increasingness stops. You get sequences like {3,4,5} {9,12,45,23049,2123455}.
- The second one is trickier - It doesn't matter if increasingness continues, if you have three numbers in an increasing sequence it counts. In that interpretation input 3,4,5,6,7 leads to {3,4,5} {4,5,6} {5,6,7}, and possibly even {3,4,5,6} {4,5,6,7} and {3,4,5,6,7}.

This is pure speculation, but it would fit quite nicely if they asked for the second interpretation (hopefully in non-ambiguous way) with sequence length = 3. Than your input would indeed return 14.